# I am having trouble hiding my divs created through DOM manipulation

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, show-hide

So far I am only able to toggle the content on the first div created through jquery, but the others aren't responding to the click event. I am trying to make a hover/click event to toggle a hidden div containing description and title, but I am not sure if it has to do something with neighbor, or child?

```
var projects = [
    {
      link: "https://jpimentel45.github.io/Giftastic/",
      img: "assets/images/giftstic.png",
      text: "   Giftastic",
      description: "Blah Blah Blah"
    },
    {
      link: "https://jpimentel45.github.io/TrainSchedule/train",
      img: "assets/images/train.png",
      text: "Train Schedule",
      description: "Blah Blah Blah"
    },
    {
      link: "https://jpimentel45.github.io/TriviaGame/",
      img: "assets/images/trivia.png",
      text: "Trivia Game",
      description: "Blah Blah Blah"
    },
    {
      link: "https://jpimentel45.github.io/Psychic_Game/",
      img: "assets/images/psychic.png",
      text: "Psychic Game",
      description: "Blah Blah Blah"
    }
  ];
  var port = '<div class="wrapper">';
  $("#portfolio").html(port);
  function createProject() {
    $(".wrapper").empty();
    //create array to hold start <option> tags
    var newProjects = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
      var projectDiv = $("<div id='show'>");
      var newOption = $("<a>");
      var img = $("<img src='' id='portImg'>");
      img.attr("src", projects[i].img);
      var text = $('<p id="txt">');
      text.text(projects[i].text);
      var desc = $("<p id = 'description'>");
      desc.text(projects[i].description);
      newOption.attr("href", projects[i].link); // add [i] here to index element

      //on media query for l phone remove .hide for div#hide and set to show
      var hideDiv = $("<div id='hide'>");    
      projectDiv.append(img);
      newOption.append(text);
      newOption.append(desc);
      hideDiv.append(newOption);     
      projectDiv.append(img);     
      projectDiv.append(hideDiv);
      newProjects.push(projectDiv); // add new option to the array
    }

    $(".wrapper").html(newProjects); // once loop is complete, add the array of elements to the DOM
  }
  createProject();
  //only toggles first pctures hide div not on others
  for (i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
    console.log(projects[i]);
    $("#show").click(function() {
      $("#hide[i]").toggle();
    });
  }
```

I am trying to have my project image displayed, and when i hover on computer, or click event for phone, will display the hidden div containing < a > text & description. So far only the first div is working for the click event

Comment: id are unique, what your need is class, the reason why only first div hides because its the first id

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Aditya Thakur, I was able to resolve my issue. The solution to my problem is to change the div's from id to classes, that way it targets all div's created on my portfolio and toggle the hidden container containing the description